# Creating reservations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, associations

I have an application that allows users to create loads and bid on them.

I want a way to go through the application and reserve a bid which will then process a credit card, but I am having issues setting up the reservation model. Here is the setup:

Models with their associations:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :load
  belongs_to :bid

  validates :load_id, presence: true
  validates :bid_id, presence: true
end

class Load < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_one :reservation
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :load
  has_one :reservation
end
```

The reservation migration only includes the references to the two tables.
In my reservations controller I have the following code:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_load
  before_filter :find_bid 

  def new
    @reservation = @load.build_reservation(params[:reservation])
  end

  def create
    @reservation = @load.build_reservation(params[:reservation].merge!(:bid_id => params[:bid_id])) 
    if @reservation.save
      flash[:notice] = "Reservation has been created successfully"
      redirect_to [@load, @bid]
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def find_load
    @load = Load.find(params[:load_id])
  end

  def find_bid
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  end
end
```

In my config routes file I have the following:

```
resources :loads do 
  resources :bids do 
    resources :reservations
  end
end
```

The migration for the reservations model looks like this:

```
def change
  create_table :reservations do |t|
    t.references :load
    t.references :bid
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

The View Code:

```
<h4>Reserve this bid: </h4>
  <dl>
    <dt>Carrier</dt>
    <dd><%= @bid.user.email %></dd>
    <dt>Bid Amount:</dt>
    <dd><%= @bid.bid_price %></dd>
 </dl>

<%= form_for [@load, @bid, @reservation], :html => {:class => 'payment_form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
<fieldset>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Back of Card (CVV)" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
    <%= select_month nil, { add_month_numbers: true }, { name: nil, id: "card_month" } %>
    <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15 },
  { name: nil, id: "card_year" } %>
 </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I go to submit the form, I get the following validation error: "Bid can't be blank". It looks like the form is submitting the bid as `nil`, and I am unsure of why it is doing this. I don't believe the first line of code is correct in my create action of the controller, and I have tried all of the permutations that I could think of and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Which line is giving you an error? Most likely it can't find a load by `load_id`

Comment: Reservations Controller; @reservation = load.reservation.build It can find both the load and bid because the parameters hash has both values. I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: Clearly your `reservation` is `nil`, make sure you have it set in your database

Comment: I have already migrated the database, is there another reason why it might be returning nil?

Comment: your reservation table should have a `load_id` column and it needs to have a proper id

Comment: Could you post your view code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form doesn't contain any data you'll be saving you can simply do this:

```
@reservation = @load.build_reservation(:bid_id => @bid.id)
```

If you add reservation fields that you want to save in the future, `params[:reservation]` will not be `nil` and you will be able to do:

```
@reservation = @load.build_reservation(params[:reservation].merge(:bid_id => @bid.id))
```

Another way would be to add a hidden field to your form that contains the `bid_id`, but since you already have it in the URL, this may not be the best approach.

Comment: you are correct it should be params[:reservation], however when I add the merge method onto params[:reservation] I get "undefined method `merge!' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Hm, apparently `params[:reservation]` is `nil`. Can you try to debug your `params` hash and see what's in there after you submit the form?

Comment: Hmmm this is weird the params hash looks like this: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AVkc4PWygoH4OZUlQl5Z1g3KCirZ+FcW03kmNcwXx0M=",
 "load_id"=>"37",
 "bid_id"=>"20"}; which makes me extremely confused since the bid_id is there and I am getting a nil value for the params hash entirely

Comment: What columns do you have in your reservations table? Will you store the credit card info in there? Any other data besides `load_id` and `bid_id`?

Comment: Those are the only two values in the table right now, the credit card data is sent to Stripe to generate a token, that data will not be persisted.